# configuring petsc with --CC compiler (mopish) on silicon Apple Mac M1 MAX

Tags: mpich, cc

configuring petsc with following command on zsh
`./configure \`
  `--CC=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpich/4.1.2/bin/mpicc`
  `--CXX=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpich/4.1.2/bin/mpicxx`
  `--FC=opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpich/4.1.2/bin/mpif90`
  `--PETSC_ARCH=$PETSC_ARCH`
  `--with-debugging=1`
  `--download-hypre=1`
   `--with-x=0`
`make -j4`
`make -j4 test`

As you can see, default brew installation path has already been changed to /opt/homebrew/ where link files can be found (here I specified actual location of compiler. Unfortunately, the message I get is the following:

#### =============================================================================================

Configuring PETSc to compile on your system

TESTING: checkCCompiler from config.setCompilers(config/BuildSystem/config/setCompilers.py:1420)

---

```
       UNABLE to CONFIGURE with GIVEN OPTIONS (see configure.log for details):
```

---

C compiler you provided with -CC=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpich/4.1.2/bin/mpicc cannot be
found or does not work.
If the above linker messages do not indicate failure of the compiler you can rerun with
the option --ignoreLinkOutput=1